# Should I raise a custom exception?

Tags: python, mysql

Trying to figure out the most correct pythonic way to handle an error case.

- main.py - calls into a custom class call database_class located in database.py
- database.py - uses mysql.connector to make a connection, BUT if that database doesn't exist I catch the mysql exception and parse out if it's because of an unknown database. IE:

  ```
  try:

      self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=host,
                                          database=db_name,
                                          user=username,
                                          password=password,
                                          port=port,
                                          charset='utf8')

      if self.conn.is_connected():
          self.logger.info("Connected to mysql database: {}".format(db_name))

  except mysql.connector.Error as err:
      if 'Unknown database' in str(err.msg):
          self.logger.error("The database does not yet exist I can't continue...")
  ```

  raise

The problem I have is the 'raise' if I just raise the error than main.py has to understand how to parse mysql exceptions and i'm trying to avoid that.  So should I create a custom exception handler here for my database_class?

Comment: Note that there might be better ways to get infos about the exact error (it could be a specific subclass or hold more reliables infos in `err.args`).

Comment: I think it would be fine to not catch the error here at all but catch it in main, and just print the error message.  Can your users can read the message and understand what it means?

Comment: I catch the error because i verify and save the connection in my object.  I just don't want to have to import the mysql.connector into main.  however maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way.